# iAmAnIntentionalENoticeThatWarnsOfAProblemYouShouldReport and other event registration warnings in 4.7.1

Tags: civievent, drupal, upgrade, 4.7

On the Find Participants page for an event:

```
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in CRM_Utils_Array::formatArrayKeys()
```

In the Drupal log, lots of these:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: iAmAnIntentionalENoticeThatWarnsOfAProblemYouShouldReport in CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::buildClause() (line 5382 of /home/[site]/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php).
```

And these:

```
Cache rebuild lock hit: event_init
```

And when viewing a contact, these:

```
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in CRM_Utils_Array::formatArrayKeys() (line 1037 of /home/[site]/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Array.php).
```

And these:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: onlySubType in CRM_Custom_Form_CustomData::setGroupTree() (line 163 of /home/[site]/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Custom/Form/CustomData.php).
```

And these:

```
Warning: Missing argument 4 for CRM_Custom_Form_CustomData::setGroupTree(), called in /home/[site]/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Custom/Form/CustomDataByType.php on line 56 and defined in CRM_Custom_Form_CustomData::setGroupTree() (line 153 of /home/[site]/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Custom/Form/CustomData.php).
```

It looks like these are related to paid event registration - the client is complaining that the transactions (using Authorize.net) are taking a long time to process and are even timing out.

It looks like going to 4.7 was a big mistake, but now I'm stuck - any ideas? And help greatly appreciated...

Comment: There seem to be a few reports here of people hitting issues with older PHP, so maybe add that to your question. It might help to report the CiviCRM version your site was upgraded from, and confirm whether all the steps were followed from the [upgrade documentation](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades).

Comment: Chris is right, this sounds like you're using an end-of-life version of PHP.  For others who may come across this - it's critical to update your database on a test server first, and keep a database backup so you can revert in the event of serious errors.

Comment: Thanks, but PHP is 5.5.31, which, as the system status report says, "meets or exceeds the minimum recommendation of 5.5."

This is also a fresh Civi installation as far as I can remember, although it is possible that I originally did the development deployment of the site with 4.6.11 and upgraded to 4.7 before launch.

Comment: One other thing (and I should open a separate issue for this) - there are a **lot** of extensions available in 4.6 that are unavailable in 4.7. There's no indication of this in the (fairly emphatic) upgrade warning that Civi "requires a security update." Users should know that it's quite possible that they'll lose significant functionality upon upgrade.

Comment: Bottom line: It looks to me like upgrading to 4.7 is potentially very fraught for production sites. Users should be warned before upgrading.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated - in the meantime, I'm going to see if I can manage to do a downgrade, which in my case, would be reproducing the existing data on 4.6.11 and then switching Civi out. Yikes.

(Any suggestions welcome on that topic as well.)

Comment: I am also seeing this error - Notice: Undefined variable: onlySubType in CRM_Custom_Form_CustomData::setGroupTree() (line 163 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Custom/Form/CustomData.php).

Comment: FWIW, we just updated a site to 4.7.8 and have similar problems with Authorize.Net and event registrations (timeouts, whitescreens, numerous warnings, etc.). Ironically, we upgaded to 4.7 out of an abundance of caution regarding the Authorize.Net Akamai and other changes which have since been postponed. Our PHP is 5.5.35.

Comment: I am in Civi 4.7.6, and have those same messages sometimes, which seem to have no consequence, so I don't pay so much attention : I will try to identify when this occurs

Answer (score 1):

That is a lot of errors, so here are a few answers.

1. Not helpful for you, but in response to your last few comments, I'd say you should also be testing upgrades before doing them on a production site, and making sure you've backed up your site so you can roll it back in case of disaster. That is particularly true of a complex existing site, which appears might be true in your case.
2. You posted this some time ago when 4.7 was relatively new, so I'd guess that the latest 4.7 will have resolved many of these problems. I agree that early 4.7 releases perhaps should have come with more warnings. Releases do go through a lot of testing, but CiviCRM is a complex code base and especially when you are using it in non-standard ways, there can be some subtle issues that arise.
3. Your collection of warnings and notices need to be addressed one at a time, it's not necessarily one problem and solution. Some of them may be connected, but the limited error log you've posted above doesn't give us enough to go on. You'll need to dig into the CiviCRM error log in the files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog directory where a more complete backtrace should be. Looking at the datestamps and order of the errors will give you a good idea of which of the errors/notices are the key ones to look at, and which ones are just symptoms of the earlier problem.
4. iAmAnIntentionalENoticeThatWarnsOfAProblemYouShouldReport is a clever mechanism that I believe Eileen introduced to help diagnose issues. I'd start with that one as being the most helpful symptom of what might be the key issue, which is likely related to custom values.
5. The cache rebuild lock hit might also be a key symptom - i.e. if there are resource issues, that might cascade down into some of the other issues.